# Choosing controllers as post category in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create my first rails app. I am creating a cycling store app where there will be 3 different pages. "Bikes", "Kids Bike" and "Accessories". My question is how can I choose one of these three category while creating a new post in my app. I was planning to create 3 different controllers called "Bikes", "Kids Bike" and "Accessories" and there will be a `f.select` syntax to select the controller but I am not sure if it's possible or not. Can someone please tell me if I can implement this idea or if there is any better way then please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Creating three controllers sounds wrong if these are simply different records in the same table. Why not one controller with a parameter in the URL that leads to the right page?

Comment: yeah but how can I choose a specific page while creating new post? Suppose I wants to add a new post which I wants to appear on "Kids Bike" page. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comments - you don't want three controllers. "Bikes", "Kids Bike" and "Accessories" all sound like types of products you're selling in the cycling store. These would all be categories of the products. So maybe a product model with a reference to categories. Categories would be a foreign key in your product model. Then each category would be in this reference table.

You'd then have a products controller and this would take care of your standard REST actions for the model (in your case the various pages/posts you want to show). So each product's page would be managed by the products controller. If you then wanted to display all products that were "Accessories", there are a variety of ways you could handle this.

To show all products in a category, you could either pass a category parameter and then filter your search in the show method to just return those products as mentioned by @tadman in the comments.

Overall, albeit very over simplified, try to think of your controllers as actions and your models as the things. The controllers should not contain the business logic.

Comment: There's different schools of thinking here: Fat models and thin controllers versus thin models and fat controllers. Both are valid depending on your approach, so it's often a very subjective thing.